# Entity Framework with MySQL MissingManifestResourceException

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I'm trying to migrate a .NET webservice from MsSql to MySql. I followed the steps from this tutorial to make MySql working: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

The MsSql database structure and data is transformed into a MySql database.

When I try to get data from the MySql database via Entity (ex. `db.Languages.FirstOrDefault()`) or try to do anything with the Package Manager Console (ex. `Update-Database`) I always get this exception:

```
System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.Properties.Resources.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.
   at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.HandleResourceStreamMissing(String fileName)
   at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Dictionary`2 localResourceSets, Boolean tryParents, Boolean createIfNotExists, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo requestedCulture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo culture)
   at MySql.Data.Entity.Properties.Resources.get_NoStoreTypeForEdmType()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderManifest.GetStoreType(TypeUsage edmType)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.StructuralTypeMappingGenerator.MapTableColumn(EdmProperty property, String columnName, Boolean isInstancePropertyOnDerivedType)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.PropertyMappingGenerator.Generate(EntityType entityType, IEnumerable`1 properties, EntitySetMapping entitySetMapping, MappingFragment entityTypeMappingFragment, IList`1 propertyPath, Boolean createNewColumn)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.TableMappingGenerator.Generate(EntityType entityType, DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.DatabaseMappingGenerator.GenerateEntityTypes(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.DatabaseMappingGenerator.Generate(EdmModel conceptualModel)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ModelBeingInitialized()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(DbContext context, XmlWriter writer)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetModel>b__0(XmlWriter w)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(Action`1 writeXml)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(DbContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState, Boolean calledByCreateDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.GetMigrator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.RunCore()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
```

I have deleted all migrations and the __MigrationHistory table.

Visual Studio 2015, .NET 4.5.2, EntityFramework 6.2.0, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6 6.10.7.0, MySql database version: 5.6.15.

Please help me how to solve this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading MySql.Data.Entity from 6.10.7 to 6.9.12 "solved" this issue.